# How can I get to the unit test in Test Explorer from the unit test source code?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit.net

In Visual Studio (2019) if I have my cursor in a unit test, I can type `ctl + =` to get to that code file in solution explorer.  Is there key combination that will take me to that test in the Test Explorer from the unit test's source code?

I feel like I'm always hunting for a test in Test Explorer and it seems like there should be a way to jump right into Test Explorer at that test if I'm on the test in the code.  How can I do that?